# Browserify building language packs (conditional loading)

Tags: browserify

I develope and bundle ES6 app using browserfy.
I have many components in app.  Each component has serveral related language files (dictinoaries in from of js modules). I want to split it to dirrent bundles for each language.

```
bundle.js
bundle.en.js
bundle.es.js
```

and load them conditionaly on the client (depending on selected language in the app).

How is it possible to accomplish using browserify?

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? :-)